# Does Directory Traffic count towards Consensus Weight?

Tags: relays, directory, bandwidth, consensus

When I have a node running, lets say an Entry Guard, that also acts as a Directory Mirror. Will the bandwidth used sending directory information also count towards the consensus weight?

And if so or if not so, what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. (..and neither does the OR traffic.)

The idea that '*traffic counts towards consensus weight*' is not how it works. As I understand (from the linked document), the bandwidth is *measured* by building a circuit through the relay and transferring a file through it (and measuring how long that takes). So the consensus weight is not determined any *amount of traffic* (neither *OR* nor *DIR*) that the relay reports, but by periodic bandwidth measurements from Bandwidth Authorities.

See [Bandwidth Scanner specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torflow.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/NetworkScanners/BwAuthority/README.spec.txt) especially section 1.4, 1.5

Comment: Okay, traffic is the wrong term then. But transfer rate is the right one. The question still holds though. Does that mean that the relay being busy with directory stuff in place of being able to use the bandwidth for the measurement?

Comment: Then it comes down to 'Does DIR traffic affect available OR bandwidth? / Does DIR traffic count towards `RelayBandwidthRate`?' I believe it does. Any DIR traffic (or OR traffic for that matter) _at the time of the measurement_ can affect the measurement if your relay is at capacity at that time.